# how can I invoke an ember component dynamically via a variable?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Lets say I have an array of widget objects on my controller and each widget object has member variable that is assigned the name of a component class.  How can I get my template to invoke that component?

```
//widgets[0].widget.componentClass="blog-post"

{{#each widget in widgets}}
    {{widget.componentClass}}
{{/each}}
```

Obviously the above example just spits out a series of string versions of the widget component classes.  This however does work (as long as you got everything set up right):

```
//widgets[0].widgets.viewClass="blogPost"

{{#each widget in widgets}}
    {{view widget.viewClass}}
{{/each}
```

That was our previous implementation, but we weren't happy with it.  We're currently using a custom {{renderWidget ...}} tag with a handlebars helper as described here: [Calling Handlebars {{render}} with a variable name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16556631/calling-handlebars-render-with-a-variable-name).  The default render helper has a similar problem where it would not invoke a render on the contents of a variable name.  I'd be willing to write a custom component handlebars helper but I can't even figure out where to start.  Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Ember 1.11, the [new `component` helper](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/10093) allows you to do this:

```
{{#each widget in widgets}}
  {{component widget.componentClass}}
{{/each}}
```

As of today, Jan 19th, 2015, 1.11 is not a stable release but this feature is in [the canary version](http://emberjs.com/builds/#/canary).

Comment: Very nice feature, just not sure how to pass through additional parameters.

Comment: `{{component widget.componentClass var1=item var2=this}}` should work?

Answer (score 12):

I tried this and it seems to work, but its just a lot of guesswork on my part:

```
Ember.Handlebars.registerHelper('renderComponent', function(componentPath, options) {
  var component = Ember.Handlebars.get(this, componentPath, options),
      helper = Ember.Handlebars.resolveHelper(options.data.view.container, component);

  helper.call(this, options);

});
```

and you use it the same way:

```
{{#each widget in widgets}}
  {{renderComponent widget.componentClass widget=widget}}
{{/each}}
```

Comment: using this pattern how would I go about modifying the call the the resolved component in order to pass some arbitrary parameter values (for instance if its a form input component, set the `value` parameter), as well as set the content that should be inserted in the component's `{{yield}}`?

Comment: @StrangeLooper This doesn't work in Ember 1.10, the error states that you should use a Component or makeBoundHelper instead. after changing it to a bound helper i get an error saying the **renderComponent** helper was not found. any clues? a refactored version for Ember 1.10 perhaps? thanks

Answer (score 6):

Sounds like I've run into a lot of the same problems as you. All components are registered as top level helpers, which means you can do a similar method to the one you linked of creating a handlebars helper that does the lookup. Like this:

```
Ember.Handlebars.registerHelper('lookup', function(component, options) {
  component = Ember.Handlebars.get(this, component, options);
  Ember.Handlebars.helpers[component].call(this, options);
});
```

Then in your template:

```
{{#each widget in widgets}}
  {{lookup widget.componentClass}}
{{/each}}
```

Here's a jsbin with a working example: http://jsbin.com/ucanam/2482/edit

Hope that helps!

### -- edit --

For some reason, the new version of handlebars makes calling helpers from other helpers impossible. Instead you can lookup the template through the `Ember.TEMPLATES` global. I've updated the JSBin to use this method.

You can also get the template via `options.data.view.templateForName(component)`, but it feels a bit more brittle than `Ember.TEMPLATES`.

### -- edit 2 --

It's changed again. `Ember.Handlebars.resolveHelper` is now the correct way to do it. See @StrangeLooper's answer.

Comment: This seems to be not working for latest ember. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: just tried implementing this helper and it doesn't seem to be invoking the js part of the component, just the template part.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Ember CLI and Coffeescript here is a version for that.  Create the following file in `app/helpers/render-component.coffee`:

```
renderComponent = (componentPath, options)->
  helper = Ember.Handlebars.resolveHelper(options.data.view.container, componentPath)
  helper.call this, options

`export { renderComponent }`
`export default Ember.Handlebars.makeBoundHelper(renderComponent)`
```

From there, you can call `{{render-component "foo-bar"}}` from a template.

Since the Ember ecosystem is ever changing, here is the version I tested it on:

- Ember-CLI v0.0.43
- Ember v1.7.0
- Handlebars 1.3.0