# Dynamically swapping out components in Ember.js

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I have a template that might render one of many different components. In the controller, I define which component is currently active, and then want to render it with something like:

```
{{render-component activeComponent}}
```

Unfortunately, the `render-component` part of things doesn't work. I followed the example I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18972202/how-can-i-invoke-an-ember-component-dynamically-via-a-variable), but it's throwing the error: `undefined is not a function`.

In the example I linked to, they're passing in a second parameter like `{{renderComponent widget.componentClass widget=widget}}`, and perhaps since I'm not doing the same, that's why I'm getting this error? I tried passing `this`:

```
{{render-component activeComponent this}}
```

But I get the same error. Any tips? Unfortunately, I can't find any documentation on Handlebars's `resolveHelper`, which seems to be at the heart of the issue.

Comment: The `renderComponent` helper in the question linked works but partially: it is not bound to the component name (so the helper does not re-render the component when its name changes), as you can [see in the JSBin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/yawoyefohiku/1/edit?html,js,output). Unfortunately, [bound helpers does not support insertions of child views at this time](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Handlebars.html#toc_use-with-blocks-not-supported)

Comment: That's too bad. Thanks for the tip, though.