# How to dynamically load ember components by name in a template?

Tags: ember.js

My question is basically the same as on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18972202/how-can-i-invoke-an-ember-component-dynamically-via-a-variable), but I can't get the code to work with ember 1.7.0 and & ember-cli.

I have a `widget` property in my model, and in my template I want to have something like:

```
{{#each question in questions}}
{{#with question}}
  <label>{{title}}</label>
  {{render-component widget params=params}}
{{/with}}
{{/each}}
```

And a question model that looks like:

```
{ id: 6,
  title: "Is this a yes/no situation?",
  help_text: 'Pick an option',
  widget: 'yes-no',
  params:
  {
    yes: {
      text: 'You picked yes',
      class: 'success'
    },
    no: {
      text: 'Be careful, you picked no',
      class: 'danger'
    }
  }
}
```

I've created a `render-component` helper that contains the following:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

function renderComponent(componentPath, options) {
  console.log('inside helper with comp=' + componentPath + ', opts=' + options);
  var component = Ember.Handlebars.get(this, componentPath, options);
  var helper = Ember.Handlebars.resolveHelper(options.data.view.container, component);
  return helper.call(this, options);
}

export {
  renderComponent
};

export default Ember.Handlebars.makeBoundHelper(renderComponent);
```

But this doesn't work. `component` is undefined. The API docs for [Ember.Handlebars.get](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Handlebars.html#method_get) aren't very helpful in explaining what the `options` parameter is. Also, there's no mention of a `resolveHelper` method in the docs now, so I don't know if the code is out of date anyway.

How can I load components by name from a variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so it should be:

`helpers/render-component.js`:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

function renderComponent(componentPath, options) {
  console.log('inside helper with comp=' + componentPath + ', opts=' + options);
  var helper = Ember.Handlebars.resolveHelper(options.data.view.container, componentPath);
  return helper.call(this, options);
}

export {
  renderComponent
};

export default Ember.Handlebars.makeBoundHelper(renderComponent);
```

Use with:

```
{{render-component widget params=params}}
```

Comment: could you provide a compatible version for Ember 1.10? I'm trying to load components by name within a {{#each}} block and send params to them. thanks

Comment: Please give more examples how to pass bindParam and other params? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29412559/how-to-render-component-helper-by-name-from-instance-field thx in advance

Comment: Looks like you no longer need a custom helper to accomplish this: https://guides.emberjs.com/release/components/defining-a-component/#toc_dynamically-rendering-a-component

Answer (score 4):

This question is quite out of date. Ember includes a [built-in dynamic component helper](https://emberjs.com/api/ember/3.7/classes/Ember.Templates.helpers/methods/component?anchor=component) and has for a long time.

Answer (score 0):

Another one implementation for render-component you can find here

https://github.com/vvs-code/ember-render-helper

It allow pass name and argument/parametrs from dynamical properties