# How to render component/helper by name from instance field?

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js, ember-cli

Is there way to use component from controller/view  field

So instead of using

```
{{contact-select label="Label:" contacts=form.prop}}
// or
{{input-field label="Label:" contacts=form.prop}}
// or
{{datepicker-component label="Label:" contacts=form.prop}}
```

use some like

```
{{context.helperName label="Label:" contacts=form.prop}}
```

I try use ember-helpers-render-component but it doesn't take component name from property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [component helper](http://emberjs.com/blog/2015/03/27/ember-1-11-0-released.html#toc_component-helper) that was introduced in 1.11.0. Unfortunately there was no built-in way to do it before 1.11.0. If you're not able to upgrade, [this thread](http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/programmatically-rendering-ember-components/6986) can point you in the direction of writing your own helper.

Answer (score 0):

At version 1.11 there are component helper

for early versions i found relative question / answers:
[How to dynamically load ember components by name in a template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25946805/how-to-dynamically-load-ember-components-by-name-in-a-template)
[how can I invoke an ember component dynamically via a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18972202/how-can-i-invoke-an-ember-component-dynamically-via-a-variable)

For my goals i adapt code so

https://github.com/vvs-code/ember-render-helper

and now i can use in my template

```
{{renderComponent field.type _param=field.value label=field.label}}
```

to get the same as

```
{{input field.value label=field.label}}
```

P.S> as variat - it possible get code from https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/10093 and port it into project directly