# Ember js, HTMLbars: use component as param of a component

Tags: ember.js, htmlbars

I want to to something like this:

```
{{component-one title=(component-two paramX paramY)}}
```

the component helper does not work here, I tried this

```
{{component-one title=(component 'component-two' params)}}
```

I also tried to make a helper rendering my component but failed. Seems that all answers I found are outdated like this one
[how can I invoke an ember component dynamically via a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18972202/how-can-i-invoke-an-ember-component-dynamically-via-a-variable?lq=1)

To be more specific for my usecase. I use tooltipster and want to render a tooltip with a button init.

```
{{#tool-tipster title=(my-comp params) ... }}
```

------ UPDATE---------

The problem is, that I need in the end a HTML String for the title with a button and a data-ember-action. I can't use the tpl of the wrapper component. If I extend the tool-tipster it looks like this:

```
export default TooltipsterComponent.extend({
  title: 'title as html string'
  //other tooltipster options go here with "optionname: optionvalue"
});
```

So I thought already about something like this:

```
title: function() {
  //load component and return rendered component by hand
}}
```

But this brings me back to my problem that I was not able to render any component by hand.

Thx for every input!

Cheers
Pi

----- UPDATE -------

altrim on gitbub provided me the exact solution for my problem: https://github.com/altrim/tooltipster-content-component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this, but you need to use the component helper twice:

First to pass the component:

```
{{wrap-component child=(component 'pass-component' name="blah")}}
```

And next inside the `wrap-component.hbs` to call the component:

```
{{component child}}
```

Checkout this [ember-twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/f02d5c22ceffc5ad4ee299e8f08aa393?openFiles=templates.components.pass-component.hbs%2Ctemplates.components.wrap-component.hbs).

Comment: Thx for the twiddle. The problem is that I can't use the wrappers tpl :(. Sorry for missing this information. I updated the question. Is there a other way you can think of? thx alot

Answer (score 1):

Using the `title=(component 'component-two' params)` was the correct idea, but i am *pretty sure* you cant use positional params in the component helper other than for resolving the name.. so you would need to do this instead: `title=(component 'component-two' params=params)`

When you want to render that component inside of `component-one` you will need to use the component helper again like this:  `{{component title}}`

This is at least how i get it to work.. I am fairly confident it is the "ember" way to do it.

Comment: even if I leave the params away I always only get a "Cannot read property 'getState' of null". I am actually not quite sure what you mean with "use the component helper again" for the title. thx for the help

Comment: oh... i see what you are trying to do now... the title attribute normally on an html element can only be a string.. you cannot pass a component into title

Comment: instead, i would search for an ember addon or a js plugin that handles custom tooltips

Comment: Your right, it must be a string. So far I had a helper connecting some lines html. Is there no way to get the components rendered html with the data-ember-action? At this point of my project changing away from tooltipster is no option :( . Updated Question.